# Python: how to find the element in a list which match part of the name of the element

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of keyword  to find from a list of file name. Example, if the keyword is `'U12'`, I want to find the csv file that contain `'U12'` which is `'h_ABC_U12.csv'`and print it out.

```
word = ['U12','U13','U14']
file_list = ['h_ABC_U12.csv','h_GGG_U13.csv','h_HVD_U14.csv','h_MMMB_U15.csv']

for x in range (len(word)):
    if word[x] in file_list:
       #print the file name
```

This is part  of the code but unable to continue after some searches.
I need the full name that match the word to print out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `os.path.splitext` to get the filename without extension.

```
>>> from os.path import splitext
>>> for f in file_list:
...     name = splitext(f)[0]
...     if any(name.endswith(tail) for tail in word):
...         print(name)
... 
h_ABC_U12
h_GGG_U13
h_HVD_U14
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
for w in word:
     for file in file_list:
         if w in file:
             print file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using list comprehension:

```
word = ['U12','U13','U14']
file_list =['h_ABC_U12.csv','h_GGG_U13.csv','h_HVD_U14.csv','h_MMMB_U15.csv']

print [i for i in file_list for b in word if b in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely

```
for x in range(len(word)):
    for file in file_list:
        if x in file:
            print file
```

Would do the job?

Answer (score 0):

This should perform better:

```
for file_name in file_list:
    the_word = next((w for w in word if w in file_name), None)
    if the_word:
        print the_word
        print file_name
```

Or to get the list of all file names:

```
[file_name for file_name in file_list if next((w for w in word if w in file_name), None)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = ['U12','U13','U14']
file_list = ['h_ABC_U12.csv','h_GGG_U13.csv','h_HVD_U14.csv','h_MMMB_U15.csv']

for file_name in file_list:
  for w in word:
    if w in file_name:
      print(w,file_name)
```

**RESULT**

```
U12 h_ABC_U12.csv
U13 h_GGG_U13.csv
U14 h_HVD_U14.csv
```